# Running a Universal Robot Urp or Script file from ROS PC

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to run a Universal Robot Urp file or Script file from ROS PC to control a UR robot in the simulator(rviz/Gazebo)? The use case is that:
I have a program (URP file) that is used to move the robot without collision to the home position during a process. And now I want it to test this program for its functionality from anywhere in the work space.  My idea is to make a ros visualization in rviz or gazebo and to initially move the robot to a random point in the work space and call the safety program from ros pc to detect any collision in the simulator. I can record all those points where a collision is detected and I can later correct the program if I want to prevent the collision in future.

Is it possible to do this. Please let me know your suggestions. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275734/running-a-universal-robot-urp-or-script-file-from-ros-pc/) by [npa](https://answers.ros.org/users/24133/npa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it possible to run a Universal Robot Urp file or Script file from ROS PC to control a UR robot in the simulator(rviz/Gazebo)

No, that is not (directly) possible, as URScript (and the binary representation of it, `urp`) is proprietary to UR, and Gazebo (note: RViz is *not* a simulator, but a visualisation tool) has no support for it.

You could perhaps see whether `ur-sim` in combination with some other tool could be of use.

Another option: write a parser for URScript (it's very close to Python), extract the motion commands (`movej`, `movel`, etc) and then use Gazebo to do what you initially intended to do, but have a separate node command motions based on the motion statements you've extracted from the URScript file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [npa](https://answers.ros.org/users/24133/npa/) on 2017-11-13**:
Thanks a lot for your answer. I guess your second option is doable easily. But i didn't understood what you meant by " *but have a separate node command motions based on the motion statements* ". What do you mean by this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-13**:
Gazebo wouldn't 'load' or 'execute' or 'run' the URScript file directly, but a separate ROS node would parse it and construct `JointTrajectory` msgs or action goals and submit those.

**Comment by [npa](https://answers.ros.org/users/24133/npa/) on 2017-11-13**:
Ok. Got it. Thanks :)